# send file via webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, gmail, file-transfer

how can i send a file via web service in my site
same as gmail attachments
in c# and asp.net

Comment: You will need to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry dude, but you might as well ask "How do I write a program like hal in 2001 with a red light and that can talk back to me please send me some code". You need to hit google and msdn and read up on webservices, there's a dozen ways to approach this, and much will depend on what you've already done.

Comment: Here's how: put the title of your question in this textbox http://www.google.com and click the search button. This will bring you a list of links you might start reading. Once you've found one that works in your scenario you may try experimenting with the code. If you encounter some specific problems don't hesitate to come back and ask a question here by defining exactly what difficulties did you encounter with your code (by not forgetting to post your code of course). If you don't find a suitable link for your scenario try refining your search by adding keywords.

Comment: Dude, you really have to reconsider how you ask your questions around here, not to mention the comments you give to peoples answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Web Method that accepts two parameters: a byte array and a filename.

Inside the method, simply open a FileStream to a new file with the filename and write the contents of the byte array to the file. An overly simple example method (without Web Service decorations since you never specify what Web Service framework you're using):

```
public void WriteBytesToFile(string filename, byte[] contents)
{
    using(FileStream fs = 
        new FileStream("C:\\UpdloadDir\\"+filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
    }
}
```

Without more details, that's about as specific as I can get. Remember, we're not code monkeys. We're not going to write all of your code for you. If you have some code already, post it and we'll try to help you to get it to work.

Comment: please write a simple example for this 
thanks a lot

Comment: @user422944, did you miss the `we're not code monkeys. We're not going to write all of your code for you. If you have some code already, post it and we'll try to help you to get it to work.` part of Justin's answer? At least **try** writing it yourself =)

Comment: @user422944 - @Rob got it right. I'm not going to write all your code for you. I did add an overly simplified example to demonstrate purpose. Keep in mind, though, that the code I posted will cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send email attachments, investigate `System.Net.Mail`. Scott Guthrie has a good introduction on his [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/16/432854.aspx).